# The Queue program not working as it is intended to (c++)

Tags: c++, queue

I created this queue to create the binary tree, that is the reason there is another structure called the "Node". I want this qNode, which is the node for queue to store the address of the Node struct.
this is supposed to be a header file
when I tried to include a main function just to check out if this works as it should, the program is not working as it intended to .

this is the code

```
#include <iostream>

struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* lchild;
    struct Node* rchild;
};


struct QNode {
    struct Node* Node;
    struct QNode* pre;
    struct QNode* post;
};

struct Queue {
    struct QNode* first = NULL;
    struct QNode* last = NULL;


    int size;
};



void enqueue(struct Queue* Queue, struct Node* node, int size) {

    if (Queue->first == NULL && Queue->last == NULL) {
        std::cout << "created the first node";

        struct QNode* QNode = (struct QNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct QNode));
        QNode->Node = node;
        QNode->pre = NULL;
        QNode->post = NULL;
        Queue->first = QNode;
        Queue->last = QNode;
        Queue->size = size;
    }
    else
    {
        struct QNode* QNode = (struct QNode)malloc(sizeof(struct QNode));
        QNode->Node = node;
        QNode->pre = Queue->last;
        QNode->post = NULL;
        Queue->last = QNode;

    }

}

void dequeue(struct Queue* Queue) {

    if (Queue->first == NULL && Queue->last == NULL) {
        std::cout << "cannot do that since the Queue is empty";
    }
    else
    {
        struct QNode* temp = Queue->first;
        Queue->first = Queue->first->post;
        free(temp);
    }
}


int isEmpty(struct Queue* Queue) {
    if (Queue->first == NULL && Queue->last == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    struct Node root;
    struct Node root1;
    struct Node root2;

    struct Queue Q;
    enqueue(&Q, &root, 20);
    enqueue(&Q, &root1, 20);
    enqueue(&Q, &root2, 20);
    struct QNode* nodepointer = Q.first;
    while (nodepointer->post != NULL) {
        std::cout << nodepointer->Node;
        nodepointer = nodepointer->post;

    }
    dequeue(&Q);
    while (nodepointer->post != NULL) {
        std::cout << nodepointer->Node;
        nodepointer = nodepointer->post;

    }

    return 0;

}
```

I would apprecite any help.

Comment: The local variable `Q` (in main) is not initialised to anything... Then the code tries to `enqueue` data (I guess)... Back to the drawing board...

Comment: malloc in C++ is also not a good idea, for dynamic memory managment you should use new (or better std::make_unique/std::make_shared depending on ownership)
You don't have to repeat struct in the members of your struct. `Node* Node;` is fine. And if you write `Node* Node{}` your members WILL be initialized to nullptr's. Also isEmpty/enqueue would make more sense as a member function of a queue class.

Comment: @Fe2O3 the enqueue is supposed to add datas to the first, last and size ,

Comment: @GratusRichard The first `if()` in `enqueue` tests for NULLs... Why should those values be NULL in an uninitialized struct??

Comment: @Fe2O3 I don't think the first and second are uninitialized. I have declared the initial value of the struce members with null
```
struct Queue {
 struct QNode* first = NULL;
 struct QNode* last = NULL;


 int size;
};
```

Comment: The Art of Coding is to be certain... One's notions of what is or is not are totally irrelevant... Do you ever see that first message? "created fist Node"... ??

Comment: @GratusRichard Except for `cout`, this entire code is `C`.  It uses `C` idioms such as having to use the keyword `struct` everywhere, uses `malloc`, etc.

Comment: @Fe2O3 yeah i can see that message. that why i am certain that it is initialized with null

Comment: @GratusRichard `struct QNode* QNode = (struct QNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct QNode*));` -- And this is the reason why in a C++ program, use C++ idioms.  This line is wrong, in that `malloc` is not going to allocate the correct number of bytes (`sizeof(struct QNode*)`).  You should be actually creating `Queue` objects using `new` -- if you had done that, then this would not have been an issue.  If you want to write C code, then know exactly how to use `malloc`.

Comment: Note for this solution you don't need to write your own queue class (it is not a tree, but a doubly linked list). All the functionality you need is here : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque. In coding learn to reuse tested library code and concentrate on your coding on program specific problems.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Hey, thankyou somuch for replying. I tried what you said  and replaced `struct QNode* QNode = (struct QNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct QNode*));` with `struct QNode* QNode = (struct QNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct QNode));. still it does not work`

Comment: @GratusRichard -- There are multiple things wrong with your code.  It is fundamentally flawed, more due to you using pointers to memory that has already been deallocated (using `free`).  Please debug the `dequeue` function and then your usage of `nodepointer->post` later on in `main`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, It was just that I forgot to add the next value to the Qnode->post, so that the Qnode->post remained always the same;
I will paste the complete header file code here

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* lchild;
    struct Node* rchild;
};


struct QNode {
    struct Node* Node;
    struct QNode* pre;
    struct QNode* post;
};

struct Queue {
    struct QNode* first = NULL;
    struct QNode* last = NULL;


    int size;
};



void enqueue(struct Queue* Queue, struct Node* node, int size) {

    if (Queue->first == NULL && Queue->last == NULL) {
        std::cout << "created the first node" << std::endl;

        struct QNode* QNode = (struct QNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct QNode));
        QNode->Node = node;
        QNode->pre = NULL;
        QNode->post = NULL;
        Queue->first = QNode;
        Queue->last = QNode;
        Queue->size = size;
    }
    else
    {
        struct QNode* QNode = (struct QNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct QNode));
        QNode->Node = node;
        Queue->last->post = QNode;
        QNode->pre = Queue->last;
        QNode->post = NULL;
        Queue->last = QNode;

    }

}

void dequeue(struct Queue* Queue) {

    if (Queue->first == NULL && Queue->last == NULL) {
        std::cout << "cannot do that since the Queue is empty" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        struct QNode* temp = Queue->first;


        Queue->first = temp->post;
        Queue->first->pre = NULL;

    }
}


int isEmpty(struct Queue* Queue) {
    if (Queue->first == NULL && Queue->last == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

again, thanks everyone for your help and support.